# Obj-C parse seconds to dd:hh:mm:ss

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, intervals

I'm calculating difference between two dates. I've create my own solution:

```
NSDate *actualDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval sec = [eveDate timeIntervalSinceDate:actualDate];
int secondsBetween = sec;
int minBetween     = sec / 60;
int hoursBetween   = sec / 3600;
int daysBetween    = sec / 86400;

_lblDays.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", daysBetween];
_lblHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", hoursBetween % 24];
_lblMin.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", minBetween % hoursBetween];
_lblSec.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", secondsBetween % minBetween];
```

But I believe that there is a better solution for this (like native class for example) but I couldn't find anything. Could you tell me how to do it better?

Comment: [NSDateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an another way to calculate.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond
                                                 fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0];
NSInteger days = [components day];
NSInteger hour=[components hour];
NSInteger minutes=[components minute];
NSInteger sec = [components second];
```

Comment: Especially this is the correct way to do it, because it respects time switches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**NSCalendar**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCalendar/currentCalendar) and [**NSDateComponents**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/struct/c:@E@NSCalendarUnit) class for doing this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar         = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:actualDate toDate:eveDate options:0];
NSLog(@"Days->%d Hour->%d, Minute->%d, Second->%d", components.day, components.hour, components.minute, components.second);
```